# Maximum Participant Count for Event not enforced in some situation (Wordpress 5.0.8, CIVICRM 5.12.0)

Tags: civievent, participants

We saw recently that 2 event registration that were set to have a maximum number of participants.  Event A has set to a maximum number of 29 but allowed 30, and Event B has set to a maximum number of 17 but allowed 19.  Until these 2 events, the maximum number has been enforced well on the events.

When I looked at the last few  registrations (all frontend) for these 2 events, for Event A, the last  registration registered 1min after the prior 2 registrations which registered at the same time to the minute. For Event B, the last 3 registrations where all registered at the same time to the minute.  I tried to register for these events and the Event is full message is correctly shown.

Would this anomaly be due to how the registrations take place particularly when they are in close succession? Any advice and what can be done ?  I researched on the net and it seems there was a issue about max participant enforcement (CRM5039), but that was more than ten years ago, that woulnd't be the issue by know i suppose.  Any advise? Thanks.

-- Edited on 22 Sep 2020 --

Any views on this phenomena ?  Interestingly it happened again a few days ago.  I managed to get 2 participants into a event with a 1 participant limit using the following method:

1. Participant A typing in his details to register for event
2. Participant B registered later but completed his registration and pressed "Continue"
3. Participant A pressed "Continue"
4. Both participants pressed "Continue" together at the "Confirm Your Registration Information" page

This looks like a bug to me, any views ?  Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to check whether this bug also happens on newer versions of CIVICRM and unfortunately on WP 5.4.2/CIVICRM 5.21.2 this phenonmena still happens.  ie. the max number of participant is not enforce under the above circumstances.